# python comprehension consolidation to generate all_3_digit_numbers

Tags: python, for-comprehension

I'm going through the exercises in Coding the Matrix, and have gotten to this task: write a procedure all_3_digit_numbers(base, digits), where input is a positive integer base and digits is the set {0, 1,2, ..., base-1}, and the output is the set of all three-digit numbers where the base is *base.*
I was able to come up with one solution:

```
def all_3_digit_numbers(base, digits): return {a+b+c for a in [d*base**2 for d    in digits] for b in [d*base**1 for d in digits] for c in [d*base**0 for d in digits]}
```

which fits in one line. But I thought the repetition of the expression d*base**exp could be consolidated. So I also have this solution:

```
def all_3_digit_numbers(base, digits):
   [alist,blist,clist] = [[digit*base**exp for digit in digits] for exp in [0,1,2]]
   return {a+b+c for a in alist for b in blist for c in clist}
```

which is more elegant (I guess), but requires an extra expression. I was wondering if there's a way to get the best of both worlds - a comprehension that doesn't require variable assignment in a separate statement as it does the second solution, but where the list of digits to add is not repeated as it is in the first solution.

Comment: I take it you are unfamiliar with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) ?

Comment: wait, can't you just do `return range(base ** digits)`? Or I guess `set(range(base ** digits))`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen `digits` is a (redundant) set, not a number (the same as base).  For instance, `2 ** {0, 1}` makes no sense.

Comment: You need to specify whether '3-digit' number can or cannot have leading 0s.  To be extra helpful, list the desired answer for base 2.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy ahh missed that, would explain why this seemed far too easy.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy yes 3 digit number can have leading zeroes, for example: `all_3_digit_numbers(2,{0,1})` returns 
`{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` and `all_3_digit_numbers(3,{0,1,2})` returns 
`{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}`

Comment: digits is just `set(range(base))` - of course we could declare that in the code but i think the exercise wants an elegant solution without variable assignment in separate statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These intermediate lists make the code really long. No need for that:

```
def all_3_digit_numbers(base, digits): 
    return {a*base**2 + b*base + c for a in digits for b in digits for c in digits}
```

And if you want to be a little bit more fancy, use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import product

def all_3_digit_numbers2(base, digits): 
    return {a*base**2 + b*base + c for a, b, c in product(digits, repeat=3)}
```